# Parsing email address from string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, parsing, formatting

Hoping someone can help me figure this out.

I've got a load of exports of distribution lists that have been exported from exchange.

The exports look like this... [image]

I'm writing a little app to parse these and spit out a script which can be dumped straight into exchange shell to recreate the list.

So far, I've read in the output and am looping through it line by line.

What I want to do is find the position of the @ symbol in the line then grab everything before it until a space is encountered and everything after it until a space is encountered.

I've done this a million times in excel and such like, but never in vb.net and I'm not sure how to accomplish it.

Sorry if this seems like a dumb question; They're only easy if you know the answer :)

So far, I've got this (Thanks Pikoh!)...

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(strFileName) = True Then

    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(strFileName)

    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1

        TextLine = TextLine & objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine

    Loop

    output.Text = TextLine


    For Each line As String In output.Text.Split(vbLf)
        Try
            Dim testStrings As String() = New String() {line}
            Dim stringSeparators() As String = {" ", "\t"}
            Dim email1 = testStrings(0).Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1)
            Dim email2 = testStrings(0).Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1)


            MessageBox.Show(email1 & "|" & email2)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing :(")
        End Try


    Next

End If
```

Comment: [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Thanks @ Pikoh... I can use that to find the location of '@'... how do i then find the left and right spaces relative to '@'?

Comment: See my answer using `Split`.

Comment: I was going to do exactly that, but the output isn't always a set number of spaces or tabs. The one thing i can guarantee is that there is a space after the email address and a space before it.  

If i split by space, I'll end up with loads of empty array items surely?

Comment: You beat me to it... thank you, testing now.

Comment: No, that's why i use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`. Just try my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147234/discussion-between-john-and-pikoh).

Comment: Why not just use regex to get the first part of each email? then you won't get those false hits on the first two lines like you do with splits/indexes...

Answer (score 1):

In a simple case like this, the easiest way I think is just using [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx). As I don't know what's between the 2 columns, i'm going to define 2 separators: a space and a tab:

```
Dim testStrings As String() = New String() {"test     test@domain.com", "test2" & vbTab & "test2@domain.com"}
Dim stringSeparators() As String = {" ", vbTab}
Dim email1 = testStrings(0).Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last()
Dim email2 = testStrings(0).Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still do it the same way. In fact, your VBA code might have worked in VB.NET.

With a test file of:

```
Name                      PrimarySmtpAddress
----                      ------------------
_Sys.User                 sys.user@domain.com     
Joe Bloggs                joe.bloggs@domain.com 
Bill Gates                bill.gates@domain.com 
J. Someone Else              someone.else@domain.com 
Matt "M@tty" Pain         matt@example.com
```

and the code

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Function ExtractEmailAddress(s As String) As String
        Dim atPos = s.LastIndexOf("@"c)
        If atPos < 0 Then
            Return String.Empty
        End If

        Dim firstPos = atPos + 1
        Dim lastPos = atPos - 1

        Do
            firstPos -= 1
        Loop Until firstPos = 0 OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Chars(firstPos))

        Do
            lastPos += 1
        Loop Until lastPos = s.Length OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Chars(lastPos))

        Return s.Substring(firstPos + 1, lastPos - firstPos - 1)

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\temp\ExampleOutput.txt")
            While Not sr.EndOfStream
                Dim line = sr.ReadLine()
                Dim email = ExtractEmailAddress(line)
                If email.Length > 0 Then
                    Console.WriteLine(email)
                End If

            End While
        End Using

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

the output is:

> sys.user@domain.com
>   joe.bloggs@domain.com
>   bill.gates@domain.com
>   someone.else@domain.com
>   matt@example.com